# Can I get remain time during duration time

Tags: qml

I need a help~!!

I implemented a animation with two components.
The one start animation, before the other start.
code is like below

```
A.qml
PropertyAnimation {
    id: ani1
    target: comp1
    property: "height"
    to: 1000
    duration: 300
}
// if comp1.height == 300 then ani2.start()

B.qml
PropertyAction {
    target: comp2
    property: "height"
    value: 300
}
PropertyAnimation {
    id: ani2
    target: comp2
    property: "height"
    to: 1000
    duration: ?
}
// ani1 and ani2 finish times are the same.
```

So, I want to know how can I implement the value "?" ??

Real codes... not allow coupling (if possible...)

Comment: What does it mean -  implement the value "?". You need some time delay?
Btw, if you want to run one animation after the other you can use `SequentialAnimation`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run one animation after the other, you can use SequentialAnimation as folibis suggested in comment section. However, if you want to set the duration of "ani2" based on the remaining time of "ani1", you can calculate it with some data.

It seems like you want to know time passed when comp1's height becomes 300.
Assume that comp1's starting height is 100. Each QML PropertyAnimation has its easing type.
(reference: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-propertyanimation.html#easing.type-prop)

Since its default easing curve is linear, you can get the time passed when comp1's height becomes 300 with simple math. Height change in one mili-second is (1000-100)/300, which is 3. The change between the initial height and 300 is 200. Thus, about 200/3 (about 66.7) mili-seconds has passed when comp1's height becomes 300 assuming its initial height is 100.

Consequently, duration for ani2 is about 233.3 ms (300 - 66.7).
Hope this helps.